# How to get out of "std::thread::id" the same id as the "WinAPI thread-id" (on Windows)?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, c++11, visual-c++

How to get out of `std::thread::id` the same id as the "Win API thread-id" (on Windows)?

The thread-id is 9120 (`id` and `this_id`). I tried a few ANSI C++ ways, but they resulted in a different id:

[image]

Code:

```
int main()
{
    // Win API:

    const auto id = Concurrency::details::platform::GetCurrentThreadId(); // OK

    // ANSI C++:

    const std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id(); // OK (but internal only: _id)

    constexpr std::hash<std::thread::id> myHashObject{};
    const auto threadId1 = myHashObject(std::this_thread::get_id());

    const auto threadId2 = std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id());

    const auto threadId3 = std::hash<std::thread::id>()(std::this_thread::get_id());
}
```

Update:

@Chnossos suggestion works as expected:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to get a `size_t`?  Your hashing seems to work fine

Comment: @NathanOliver , I need the 9120 for debug / log coherency. The std::thread::id object holds the 9120 value. But I don't find a way to get it.

Comment: There isn't going to be a way to get that number.  Is there a reason you just don't use the thread id you get from `get_id` everywhere?

Comment: @Amit -- it "works" by accident, not by any requirement in the C++ standard.

Comment: @PeteBecker , it will be nice to have a full answer why Chnossos answer is "by accident" and why from the beginning there is a conflict, i.e. to different ids.

Comment: @Amit -- see the comments to that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on the format or value (see comments below). That being said, you can play with the [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id/operator_ltlt):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::this_thread::get_id();
    
    std::size_t sz;
    ss >> sz;

    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " vs. " << sz << std::endl;
}
```

[Try it online](https://godbolt.org/z/dEsvEjxE6)

Output is not portable and there are no guarantees around the conversion or format of the conversion. Do not use this in production code.

Comment: This isn't going to be portable, a thread ID isn't guaranteed to print as a number, let alone a decimal one.

Comment: The **only** requirement on the text produced by the `<<` operator is that id's that compare equal must have identical textual representations and if they do not compare equal their representations are distinct. More specifically, there is no requirement that the textual representation be convertible to an integer value

Comment: The OP said it was for debugging purpose so it should answer his question. Now, I've edited the answer to account for your comments.